# Having HashMap inside a HashMap - call by reference or duplicate keys?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, pass-by-reference

I was just wondering, when having a `HashMap<HashMap<Integer, Integer>, String>` and I add as key a new HashMap, does it get treated as **a duplicate key** or we have a call by reference and the value is not looked at at all?

Thanks :)

Comment: As normal, Java doesn't use pass by reference at all, but references are passed by value. I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but it does sound like something you could easily test for yourself. In general, using a map as a *key* is a pretty odd thing to require.

Comment: As far as I understood your question: the Integer is the Hash key, but it should only have 1 String that is mapped to it.

Comment: @Bonatti, the Hash Key is the HashMap having two integers as a key and value, my question was, when adding new hashmaps as keys, do they overwrite the existing HashMap, or do they get added as new keys? Does the size of the HashMap increase or remains 1 upon the addition of a new HashMap?

Comment: If I guess your intent accurately, you mean to ask whether putting a new HashMap key in the outer HashMap checks whether that key already exists by reference comparison or by actually comparing the content of the HashMap to the content of existing keys. Since HashMap overrides hashCode and equals, the answer is the latter. The contents of the added key determine if it is considered identical to an existing key.

Comment: If the key is different, then it gets added, if its equal to a key already present, then it gets overriden

Comment: @user3153278: The hash value is calculated for the key which in your case the hash value of the Object(HashMap<Integer,Integer>).. But how will you retrieve it?

Comment: @Lathy I got it, thank you as well! :)

Comment: @Eran: Can you please explain this phrase, "by actually comparing the content of the HashMap to the content of existing keys"

Comment: @Lathy when you add a new entry, the hashCode is used to locate the right bucket for that key in the map and then equals is used to compare the new key to any keys that already exist in that bucket. the key in this case is a HashMap

Comment: @Eran: Gotcha.. Thanks..I understand your statement in a different way.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The contract for the `HashMap.equals(Object)` method is:

> *"Compares the specified object with this map for equality. Returns true if the given object is also a map and the two maps represent the same mappings. More formally, two maps m1 and m2 represent the same mappings if m1.entrySet().equals(m2.entrySet())."*

Now the standard behavior of a Map is to treat keys as the same if `equals(Object)` says they are equal.

So the answer to your question is that if you have

```
  HashMap<Integer, Integer> k1 = // some map
  HashMap<Integer, Integer> k2 = // another map      
  HashMap<HashMap<Integer, Integer>, String> map = // some
```

then using `k1` and `k2` as keys in `map` would give you one entry if `k1.equals(k2)` and two entries otherwise.

And given that `k1` and `k2` are maps, we determine if they are equal by comparing their respective sets of map entries.

---

This has two obvious problems:

1. If you change `k1` or `k2` while they are keys for entries in `map`, then you break a fundamental invariant for `map`.  When that happens you will find that operations on `map` give incorrect results; e.g. `map.get(k1)` will give the wrong answer.
2. Whenever you do an operation involving a lookup on `map`, you will call `HashMap.hashCode()` for a key object.  Calculating the hash code for the key entails calculating the hashcode for each and every key and value in the map `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`.  That is expensive, especially since this `HashMap.hashCode()` does not (cannot) cache anything.

In short, using a `HashMap` as a key for another `HashMap` is a bad idea.

---

So, to answer your question:

> I was just wondering, when having a `HashMap<HashMap<Integer, Integer>, String>` and I add as key a new HashMap, does it get treated as a duplicate key or we have a call by reference<sup>a</sup> and the value is not looked at at all?

1. It will not be a duplicate key<sup>b</sup> unless the respective keys are maps with the same set of entries.  This is what `HashMap.equals(Object)` tests.
2. It is not compared as a reference; i.e. it is not compared with `==` semantics.  The `HashMap.equals(Object)` method is used for comparisons.

---

<sup>a - Note that "call by reference" terminology is not applicable to this situation.  Call by reference / call by value is about how parameters are passed when a method is called.</sup>

<sup>b - .... provided that you don't violate the invariant.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

@Stephen has given a very good conceptual explanation.
So Just in brief:

- When we are "**putting**" something in a HashMap it is internally stored in a "**table**" which is an array of "**Entry**"
- Now at which position (**bucketIndex**) of that table it will be stored will be decided based on the "**hashcode**" of the key to be stored.Before storing it JVM will check if in that **bucketIndex** any  "**Entry**" is present.This case is possible when two "keys" would have same hashcode.Now if there is an **Entry** JVM will further check if the "**key**"  itself is identical(to know identical JVM will call "**equals**" on that key) to "**key**" already present.If yes it will consider it as a **duplicate key** and update its respective value in "**Entry**". If no it will just add another entry at the same **bucket Index**.
- At time of "**getting**" the value from the map by sending a "**key**" ,similar process will run.First "**hashcode**" of the key would be extracted and depending on this the position (**bucketIndex**) of the table to be looked would be determined. Now if there is no content in that index "null" would be returned.Otherwise...
- JVM will go to that index and there is a possibility that more than one "**Entry**" can be there because more than one object can have same hashcode. Now JVM will call "**equals**" method on that **key** to check if the Key present in the table is same as the inputKey sent for retrieval of value. if "**equals**" returns true then we will get the desired value.

So in general a key will be considered as a **duplicate key** if and only if **hashcode()** for both will return same value and **equals**() will return true.

Now coming to your question *"I add as key a new HashMap, does it get treated as a duplicate key "*, **the answer is yes if and only if your new HashMap has exact same Entry i.e key,value pairs as that of an existing HashMap key.**

Because :

1. if you will have a look at **hashcode**() implemenatation of **HashMap** then you will see its hashcode is calculated based on the "Key" and "value".So if 2 hashmaps will have same  set,they will have the same **hashcode()**.
2. the **equals()** of HashMap checks if **Entry** are identical.So again if two Hashmaps will have same  set they are equal.

Now see the below code demonstrating this concept :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> keyMap=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    keyMap.put(2, 1020);
    keyMap.put(3, 1352);
    keyMap.put(23,1256);
    System.out.println("hashcode keymap1:"+keyMap.hashCode());
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> keyMap2=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    keyMap2.put(1, 100);
    keyMap2.put(4, 152);
    keyMap2.put(43,156);
    System.out.println("hashcode keymap2:"+keyMap2.hashCode()); 
    HashMap<HashMap<Integer,Integer>,String> mainMap=new HashMap<HashMap<Integer,Integer>,String>();
    mainMap.put(keyMap, "1st value");
    mainMap.put(keyMap2, "2ndvalue");
    System.out.println(mainMap);
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> keyMap3=new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    keyMap3.put(23,1256);
    keyMap3.put(3, 1352);
    keyMap3.put(2, 1020);
    System.out.println("hashcode keymap3:"+keyMap3.hashCode());
    mainMap.put(keyMap3, "3rd value");
    System.out.println(mainMap);
    if(mainMap.containsKey(keyMap3))
        System.out.println(" value retrieved is :"+mainMap.get(keyMap3));
    else
        System.out.println("key not found");

}
```

Here you can observe **keymap** and **keymap3** are having same set of key,value and same **hashcode**. So both are here **duplicate key**, hence value of **keymap** is updated by value of **keymap3**.